# Ioinic build very slow + xCode build very slow

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I guess its an overall performance question: how can I speed up my ionic build and xcode build? It takes around 2-3' for ionic build to complete, and when I build exactly the same code from my friends MacBook its just flies.. The same with xCode building on my real device. Its true, I have Early 2011 MacBook Pro with HDD. Any ideas how can I speed up this process?

Comment: "5 year old laptop performs poorly" would seem to be a good diagnosis.

Comment: Haha, I would hope that there is a way to improve the performance.. :(

Comment: There might be, but you don't give a lot of detail. Can you see what (if any) part of the system is acting as the bottleneck? Disk, memory, processor? It's unlikely to be an issue with your *code*, so you fall back to generic tips to make your system feel less old.

Comment: Honestly speaking the laptop is really not slow for day to day use: chrome, iPhoto, iTunes etc run without any issues. However, more complicated applicaitons like xCode take time to boot, to set up my project etc, and it doesnt matter how many other programs I run - there is no difference between 0 background programs and lets say 4.

Answer (score 4):

Why use X-code to build again and again.

Use "ionic run -l -s -c" while your device is connected, and you'll be able to set up live reload on your device.

(make sure you are connected to same wifi)

Comment: Wow! I need to check that out!

Comment: If you need help , comment here. PS: "gulp" task will watch your html and js files. (so any changes you make there , will change on your device instantaneously ) , but beware if you add plugins. Run the command again.